# How to implement a function using channels

Tags: go

There is a function that is running in goroutine:

```
func (c *controlUC) WebhookPool() {
    for {
        if len(c.webhookPool) == 0 {
            continue
        }
        for i := 0; i < len(c.webhookPool); i++ {
            if !c.webhookPool[i].LastSentTime.IsZero() && time.Now().Before(c.webhookPool[i].LastSentTime.Add(GetDelayBySentCount(c.webhookPool[i].SendCount))) {
                continue
            }
            var headers = make(map[string]string)
            headers["Content-type"] = "application/json"
            _, statusCode, err := c.fhttpClient.Request("POST", c.webhookPool[i].Path, c.webhookPool[i].Body, nil, headers)
            if err != nil {
                c.logger.Error(err)
                return
            }
            if statusCode != 200 {
                if c.webhookPool[i].SendCount >= 2 {
                    c.webhookPool = append(c.webhookPool[:i], c.webhookPool[i+1:]...)
                    i--
                    continue
                }
                c.webhookPool[i].SendCount++
            } else {
                c.webhookPool = append(c.webhookPool[:i], c.webhookPool[i+1:]...)
                i--
                continue
            }
            c.webhookPool[i].LastSentTime = time.Now()
        }
    }
}
// webhookPool []models.WebhookPoolElem
type WebhookPoolElem struct {
    SendCount    int
    LastSentTime time.Time
    Path         string
    Body         []byte
}
```

The `webhookPoolElem` element is added to `c.webhookpool`, after which a request is sent to the server (the path is taken from `WebhookPoolElem.path`). If the server returned a non - 200 200, then I need to send the request again, after `X` seconds (taken from `GetDelayBySentCount()`, depending on `SendCount` returns different times). The number of attempts is limited (`c.webhookpool[i].SendCount >= 2`)

But maybe this function needs to be done through channels? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say `controlUC` receiver has a field `webhookPool chan WebhookPoolElem` and init as `webhookPool: make(chan WebhookPoolElem, n)` with `n` as buffer.

You can receive elements and more or less replace `c.webhookPool[i]` to `elem`. Rewrite like this:

```
func (c *controlUC) WebhookPool() {
    for {
        elem, open := <-c.webhookPool
        if !open {
            return
        }

        if !elem.LastSentTime.IsZero() && time.Now().Before(elem.LastSentTime.Add(GetDelayBySentCount(elem.SendCount))) {
            continue
        }
        // I omit http request
        if statusCode != 200 {
            if elem.SendCount >= 2 {
                // drop message from channel, no need to do anything
                continue
            }
            elem.SendCount++
            elem.LastSentTime = time.Now()
            c.webhookPool <- elem // enqueue again
        }
}
```

I suggest buffered channel so the last send `c.webhookPool <- elem` does not block, but it's best if you place the send in a `select` so if the send can not proceed regardless of the buffer, the goroutine doesn't block:

```
select {
    case c.webhookPool <- elem:
        // success
    default:
        // can not send 
}
```